# twitter4j : How to get tweet text with anchor to hash tag and urls

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I am using twitter4j for searching and displaying tweets. Here is the code snippet

```
Query query = new Query(queryString);
                QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);

                for (Tweet tweet : result.getTweets()) {
                    System.out.pritnln(tweet.getFromUser() + ":" + tweet.getText());
                }
```

Here tweet.getText() returns plain text without anchor tag (plain text not html) even if it has hashtag and url to some website. How can I get twitter text with anchor tag as you see in twitter search result on twitter?

Comment: Is this java? Should be tagged so...

Comment: Why don't you simply parse it from the plain text? I do not think there is a stream with linked hashtags and encoded urls.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the [`EntitySupport`](http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/twitter4j/EntitySupport.html) methods to get hashtags and URLs from each tweet.  The [`URLEntity`](http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/twitter4j/URLEntity.html) and [`HashtagEntity`](http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/twitter4j/HashtagEntity.html) classes both have methods that tell you where the entity starts and ends in the text of the tweet, so you can use that information to insert link markup when you display the tweet.

Example code that extracts the URLs from recent tweets:

```
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
Query query = new Query("lizardbill");
QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);

for (Tweet tweet : result.getTweets()) {
    System.out.println(tweet.getFromUser() + ":" + tweet.getText());
    for (URLEntity urle : tweet.getURLEntities()) {
        System.out.println(urle.getDisplayURL());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [twitter-text-java](https://github.com/mzsanford/twitter-text-java). It matches the same syntax that Twitter uses.